# Добавление select через js

Tags: html, javascript

Подскажите, есть такая штука

```
<input type="text" id="val26" onblur="document.write(this.value > 10 ? 'helloworld' : 'googbyu world')" />
```

Какую штуку нужно написать вместо document.write что бы он не перезаписывал страницу (document.write формируется после загрузки страницы)

Comment: @нгш сформируйте четко ваш вопрос, что вы хотите получить в конечном итоге!?

Comment: хочу получить надпись на странице helloworld и что бы при этом основной контент не исчезал

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/2tZhU/ вот после ввода цифр в инпут пропадает весь основной контент

Comment: Ваш пример на jsfiddle - это просто пипец. То вообще ничего не показывают, то дают блин фреймворк целый ради одной неработающей строки. Вот такого было бы достаточно http://jsfiddle.net/copist/447ZB/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

document.write используется ДО момента загрузки страницы. А если после, то он стирает страницу и пишет новый контент.

Чтобы изменять содержимое страницы после загрузки, используется Document Object Model и методы для работы с ним. В частности, объект document и его методы. Вот так можно вставить текст в узел `<div>`

```
<div id="flash"><!-- текст будет тут --></div>

<input type="text" id="val26" onblur="document.getElementById('flash').innerHTML = (this.value > 10 ? 'Hello, World!' : 'Goodbye, World!')" />
```

http://jsfiddle.net/copist/447ZB/